# How to combine two objects into one

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

i have two observables that get data from Input A and B from the dom

```
const observable1 = fromEvent(this.input1.nativeElement,'keyup').pipe(map((res) => {
  const data: TestFilter = {
    name : this.input1.nativeElement.value
    }
    this.filterService.changeMessage(data)

 })).subscribe()
```

And second

```
const observable2 = this.input2.pipe(map(res => {
  this.typesArray.push(res)

  const data: TestFilter = {
   
    types : this.typesArray
  
    }
    this.filterService.changeMessage(data)

 })).subscribe()
```

In both cases, i use map to assign the input value to a data object that has the type TestFilter which can take these values:

```
  name?: string,
  types?: string[]
  character?: string[]
```

Then, the data object gets passed down to another service.

**The problem:**

If the user inputs something and observable1 is triggered, a list gets filtered based on that input. If the user is now inputting something else into observable2, the previous input is lost because a separate data object is sent.

**My approach**
When input 2 is triggered after Input one, Input 2 must re emit the last known value of input one and then merge both values into one data object which is then passed down. i tried to combine both with mergewith, but that doesnt work

```
observable1.pipe(mergeWith( observable2.pipe(map((res) => { 
 this.typesArray.push(res)} )) ),
    
        tap((res) => {
      
          const data: TestFilter = {
          name : this.input.nativeElement.value,
          types : this.typesArray
          }
         this.filterService.changeMessage(data)
        
        })
    )
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use combineLatest so you can get both values entered in both fields. The gotcha is that all have to emit at least once.

```
const o$ = combineLatest(observable1, observable2).subscribe(
  ([input1, input2]) => { ... }
);
```

I will also update the observable1 in your code to use "startWith" operator setting the default value to emit.